# Save groupby() data in a csv file - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to filter some data from my csv file and save the results.

I'm doing this,

```
from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame

df = read_csv('results.csv')

df = df.groupby(['LR', 'Optimizer', 'Activation', 'Drop rate', 'Epochs','Batch size']).mean()
df = df.drop(['kFold'],1)
df = df.drop(['Train time (segs)'],1)
df = df.drop(['T Loss','T Acc (%)', 'T Prec (%)', 'T Recall (%)', 'VN', 'FN', 'FP', 'VP'],1)
df = df.sort_values(by=['VP (%)'], ascending=False)

df.head(50)
```

And it's appearance in google colaboratory is like this,

[image]

But now, if I save the data, `df.to_csv('res.csv', index=None, header=True)`, I lose all the `groupby()` columns. How can I do it, to obtain a csv file as the picture (or similar)? It is possible to join this two "steps" on the header, to only one?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to set `index=True`:

```
df.to_csv('res.csv', index=True, header=True)
```

or you can reset the index before saving using:

```
df.reset_index().to_csv('res.csv', index=None, header=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need remove `index=False` if need `MultiIndex` in file:

```
df = df.groupby(['LR', 'Optimizer', 'Activation','Drop rate', 'Epochs','Batch size']).mean()

df.to_csv('res.csv', header=True)
```

Or convert `MultiIndex` to columns and use `index=None` parameter for omit default `RangeIndex`:

```
df = df.groupby(['LR', 'Optimizer', 'Activation','Drop rate', 'Epochs','Batch size'], as_index=False).mean()
#alternative
#df = df.groupby(['LR', 'Optimizer', 'Activation', 'Drop rate', 'Epochs','Batch size'].mean().reset_index()

df.to_csv('res.csv', index=None, header=True)
```